# the search function issue with contact system management

Tags: string, function, search, compare

```
int main (void){
    do
    {
        mainmenu:
        mainmenu();
        switch(option)
        {
                //add new contact
                case 1:addcontact(storage);savecontact(storage);
                    break;
                case 2:searchcontact();
            break;
        }
    }while(true);
}
void searchcontact()
{
    char searchname[20];
    system("cls");
    do
    {
        int find = 0;
        printf("Contact Search\n Name of the Contact:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]",&searchname);
        length=strlen(searchname);
        f=fopen("contact.txt","rb");

        system("cls");
        printf("Search the result for %s\n",searchname);
        while(fread(&storage,sizeof(storage),space,f)==true)
        {
            for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
            storage[space].name[i]=storage[space].name[i];
            storage[space].name[length]='\0';
            if(stricmp(storage[space].name,searchname)==false)
                printf("Name\t:%s\nPhone\t:%d\nE-mail\t:%s\n",storage[space].name,storage[space].hpnum,storage[space].email);
                find++;
        }
        if(find==false)
            printf("\nNo match found!");
            else
            printf("\n %d match(s) found",find);
            fclose(f);
            printf("\nTry again?\t[1] Yes\t[2] No\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
    }while(choice==true);
}
```

I having the problem with the search...after I added the contact, I cant search it out again...I search the contact by using the stricmp...while I enetered the correct name that I enetered to save the contact, it still cant search it out...keep calling me to try again. Therefore the bug mostly is at the search function there. My true value is ==1, and my false value is ==0.

Comment: Is it C code ? some functions and variables definitions are missing like option storage choice... can you give missing parts ?

Comment: @nullix it's ok...I trying to upload my coding to somewhere else, you can download it...=)
Since here can't wrote too much of coding, I rather prefer you download my file and understand my whole coding in order to let you solve my problem. =)
http://www.mediafire.com/?pkqsasr8forgjwv

Comment: i ported it to linux to test it, and fixed your function see answer.

Comment: this is quite unkind to connect once, create a profile and never read again answer people took hours to read your wonderful code. i answered.

Answer (score 0):

**fread returns a number of read items ( not true or false ... ).**

- then in your case it returns 1 only when there is only one item in the db.
- searchname is an array of char so searchname is char * (&searchname is char * *)

Sorry for code ,currently i can't past it to SO correctly, it does not want to paste c indented code. I can mail it to you.

```
void searchcontact()
{
  char searchname[20],name[20];
  clearscreen();
  do {
      int i=0;
      int find = 0;
      int found = -1;
      int local_index=i%space;
      printf("Contact Search\n Name of the Contact:\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      //        scanf("%[^\n]",searchname);
      scanf("%s",searchname);
      length=strlen(searchname);
      f=fopen("contact.txt","rb");
      clearscreen();
      printf("Search the result for %s\n",searchname);
      while ( fread(&storage[local_index],sizeof(struct contact),1,f)==1 )
    {
      if(stricmp(storage[i%space].name,searchname)==false)
        {    
          printf("Name\t:%s\nPhone\t:%d\nE-mail\t:%s\n",storage[local_index].name,storage[local_index].hpnum,storage[local_index].email);
          find++;
          found=i;
        }
      i++;
      local_index=i%space;
    }
      if(find==false) printf("\nNo match found!");
      else printf("\n %d match(s) found",find);
      fclose(f);
      printf("\nTry again?\t[1] Yes\t[2] No\n");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
    } while(choice==true);
}
```